# How to debug Java Thread in WAITING state

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to test spark 1.6 with NFS connector and submitted the job with spark-submit, the job completes successfully and its prints the results on the console as well. The web-UI also says it's completed. However, the spark-submit never terminates.

```
Took jstack output and noticed few threads are waiting.  Is there a way
to figure the reason the hang from the running process? 



"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59000c5000 nid=0x1c80 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5864e37000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000e00152f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000000e00152f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59000c0800 nid=0x1c7f in Object.wait() [0x00007f5864f38000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000e002d238> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
        - locked <0x00000000e002d238> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner" #114 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f590181e800 nid=0x1cf0 in Object.wait() [0x00007f57364eb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000e05be660> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000000e05be660> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:3188)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



"New I/O worker #35" #159 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59026f7800 nid=0x1d24 runnable [0x00007f57348ba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b22c8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b22b8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b22d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #34" #158 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59015aa000 nid=0x1d23 runnable [0x00007f57345b7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b42c8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b42b8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b42d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #33" #157 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f590183c000 nid=0x1d22 runnable [0x00007f57349bb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b62c8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b62b8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e89b62d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #32" #156 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f590183b000 nid=0x1d21 runnable [0x00007f57346b8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e899bfa0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e899bf90> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e899bfb0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #31" #155 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f590183a000 nid=0x1d20 runnable [0x00007f5734abc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e89ba2c8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e89ba2b8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e89ba2d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #30" #154 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5901839800 nid=0x1d1f runnable [0x00007f57344b6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e89be2c8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e89be2b8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e89be2d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #29" #153 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f590183e000 nid=0x1d1e runnable [0x00007f57347b9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e89c02c8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e89c02b8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e89c02d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #28" #152 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f590183d000 nid=0x1d1d runnable [0x00007f57343b5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e89a02e8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e89a02d8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e89a02f8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Hashed wheel timer #1" #117 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f59025d9000 nid=0x1d01 waiting on condition [0x00007f5734cbe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick(HashedWheelTimer.java:483)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:392)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #8" #125 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5902468000 nid=0x1cff runnable [0x00007f57350c0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e5524748> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e5524738> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e5524620> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #7" #124 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5902466000 nid=0x1cfe runnable [0x00007f57351c1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e571d718> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e571d728> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e571d6d0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #6" #123 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5902464800 nid=0x1cfd runnable [0x00007f57352c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e575b608> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e575b618> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e575b5c0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #5" #122 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5902462800 nid=0x1cfc runnable [0x00007f57353c3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e5525588> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e5525578> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e5525460> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"New I/O worker #4" #121 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5902461000 nid=0x1cfb runnable [0x00007f57354c4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000e5525ca8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000e5525c98> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000e5525b80> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "stuck" threads don't look like a problem at all.  All three are reference handlers which do finalization (or similar processing) on objects that the garbage collector has found to be unreachable.

The normal state of a reference handler thread is to be blocked waiting for objects to be delivered to it.  Like this.

In addition, the stack dumps show that each of those threads is a daemon thread.  That means that they won't stop the JVM from exiting in the normal way.

Those threads are unlikely to be the cause of your problems with spark-submit.

---

> Is the problem can be with spark-submit?

If you are asking if those 3 threads are what is causing your problem: Almost certainly, No.  (IMO)

If you are asking what the actual problem is: I don't know.  1) None of the evidence that you have presented gives me any clues, and 2) I don't have knowledge / experience with Hadoop to recognize this syndrome.

> If the tcp connections are idle, if I close the daemon thread will it help on this hang?

In general, you can't "close" a thread.  You can either try to call `Thread.interrupt` or `Thread.destroy on it.  In interrupt may be ignored.  The destroy method has been deprecated because it is **dangerous**, and may cause the submit program to go into a worse state.

In the case of those 3 threads, you should not attempt to interrupt or destroy them.  As I said, they are not what is causing the problems.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your quick response.    Is the problem can be with spark-submit?  If  the tcp connections are idle,  if I close the daemon thread will it help  on this hang?

Answer (score 0):

spark-submit has provided an option "spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false" for exiting application without waiting for completion.  This option worked for
me.

spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion --  In YARN cluster mode, controls whether the client waits to exit until the application completes. If set to true, the client process will stay alive reporting the application's status. Otherwise, the client process will exit after submission.